# python open() gives me error while opening files having a space in naming(i.e. example text.txt)

Tags: python, filenotfoundexception

when I use `open()` in python it says `FileNotFound`, only when I try to open files with spacing in naming, (for e.g. example text.txt)

I tried using `with open('Users/vandit/Desktop/example\ text.txt', 'rb') as f:`

Comment: No need to escape the space in a Python string. This is just useful in a shell command (as spaces separate arguments).

Comment: no i just drag and dropped the file in the terminal

Comment: That looks like a full path on macOS, so it should start with "/" and not have escapes - `'/Users/vandit/Desktop/example text.txt'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'\'` is only used in the shell to escape the following space. In python, you can just include the whole thing in quotes:
`with open('Users/vandit/Desktop/example text.txt', 'w') as f:`

Also (if you are on windows) if you still get an error, try prepending the string with the drive in which your Windows is installed, which is mostly `C:\`. So it will become: `with open('C:/Users/vandit/Desktop/example text.txt', 'w') as f:`

Comment: not useful, also I have to convert it to byte array due to program requirements.

Comment: ignore the `'w'` part, but use the file path as provided by @Vthechamp. There is no need for the escaped space `\ ` in your path as explained here.

Comment: but i have to take it as input from user

Comment: if I use replace function then also I get an error.

`filename = input("copy the file path with it's name and extension and paste it here to Encrypt: ")`

`filename_replace = filename.replace('\ ', " ")`

ERROR says:

Anomalous backslash in string: '\ '. String constant might be missing an r prefix.

Comment: You need to *escape* the backslash. So instead of `"\ "`, it should be `"\\ "`. Or, as the error said, you can prepend the string with the `r` prefix indicating it is a **r**aw string, and keep the string as `"\ "`.